# SSL with both local client and server

Tags: tls, java

I'm not sure whether this topic belongs in Cryptography, Programming or StackOverFlow so please forgive me if I don't add a useful question to this site.

I want to give both server and client programs (.jar archives) to my users.

- The SERVER is a mod for a game (has one `server-id`)
- The CLIENT is a smartphone that is supposed to control the game by sending messages to the server (has one `client-id`)

I wanted to keep everything encrypted so I think SSL is a good choice. 
Because the Server is actually not mine what I did was let the server create a self-signed certificate and store it

Because accepting any certificate can be exploited, e.g. the attacker could spoof the `server-id` of another server and my client app would send the internal password (not SSL related) to the attacker.
The attacker could now spoof the `client-id` and has control over a game

*How should I implement the client so that it verifies and distinguishes servers by their certificate?*

Comment: Will you centraly sign the server's certificates (so *you* act as CA) or will you do "Trust-On-First-Use"? If you do use "Trust-On-First-Use" you'd "just" verify the certificate you see this time is the same as you saw last time and then you're safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With most TLS implementations you just need to store the self signed certificate of the server in the *trusted certificate store*. You may have to add a specific option to the command line or API call to mark the certificate as trusted.

In that case the chain of the server certificate leads to a trusted certificate because the server directly uses the trusted certificate (i.e. a "chain" of one certificate).

You do need to establish trust before establishing the connection, e.g. by distributing the self signed certificate with your client application.

Comment: Could I let the server broadcast their certficates and set their `server-id` to the SHA-256 of the encoded certificate? The client would trust every certificate but would verify the `server-id`.

Comment: Anybody could send any certificate, right? So I don't see any trust relationship being established that way. If you already know the certificate then you can just as well store the certificate itself.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the client has to create an "account". The server will save `[client-id, sha256salt(password of account)]` and the client will store `[sha256(public key), password of account]`. If the attacker doesn't know the private key, he cannot decrypt incoming data. If the attacker gives any public key he won't get the account password